# How to rename 1000 class names in a Java project (Eclipse or others)?

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse

I have a Java project organized using Eclipse in linux. I want to migrate this project to Windows. But there are so many java files with only case differences in names, like AM.java, am.java, Am.java, aM.java. These four files cannot exist together in one directory under Windows. So I need to rename these files in linux before migration. like:

```
AM.java -> AM1.java
am.java -> am2.java
Am.java -> Am3.java
aM.java -> aM4.java
```

Because the java classes invoke each others, so we cannot simply rename the java file names. All references inside the files should be replaced at the same time. I know there's a rename function in Eclipse. But there are so many java classes that I cannot rename them mannually, is there a script way or program way to achieve this? based on Eclipse or other Java IDEs?

**EDIT**
There're some classes named a.java and A.java. Also there're many variables and methods named a,A. So there will be like this:

```
File 1:
class A
{
...
}

File 2:
int A = 1;

File 3:
int A(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

All I wanna to change is the class A, not the variable or method A. So we cannot simply replace the whole word, a java grammer parser seems to be necessary?

Comment: Better write a batch file.

Comment: I need to rename all references inside the files instead of just the java file names, how to write a batch?

Comment: I guess you would have to write a script indeed. How come you have classes/files that differ only by case? Does not make much sense to me, since your classes should be named according to what they do/represent, and respect CamelCase anyway.

Comment: Were those classes created manually? Why were the Java conventions ignored? I think I would create a Java program to parse the files and creating a new copy with the new class names

Comment: I think writing  script using `sed` command may resolve the issue.

Comment: If you cannot do it with `sed` you could try a [Java parser](https://code.google.com/p/javaparser/).

Comment: @PabloLozano how to update the references? not a just class file problem. These java files form a whole project.

Comment: @Ved I don't think sed can deal with the java source code? It's a really complex syntax here.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Java parser seems to be the same kind of libs with Eclipse JDT. Which is better?

Comment: @Shriram it seems that a batch cannot handle source code modification? It's a very complex syntax in Java.-

Comment: @hsluoyz Store in a map the old and the new class names and then change them in rest of files

Comment: @PabloLozano it's not a simple text replacement, because for the name "Am", this could be a class name, or a variable, or a method. All I wanna replacement is just the class name "Am"

Comment: @hsluoyz I know, I did not say it was easy. That's the reason  OldCurmudgeon recommended to use a parser.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Krusader** file explorer. Use **Multi Rename** feature. It is based on [krename](http://www.krename.net/).

- Installing on [Windows](http://www.krusader.org/documentation/kde4_win_install.html)
- Installing on [Linux](http://www.krusader.org/get-krusader/)

After renaming files as said above import the projects in eclipse. This shows many compiler errors as references are not updated. Use Search dialog(opens on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) to update the references. Repeat this for all 4 cases mentioned in your post one by one.

Refer [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-do-a-find-and-replace-in-multiple-files-in-eclipse.html?page=2) and [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/3/16/Multifile-search-and-replace-in-Eclipse).

#### Edit

After looking at your comment:

Hope you completed part 1 and its working(?). If so then,

- Just find all search term/key(Ex: AM) in entire workspace using search dialog
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all search results.
- Right click on the selection then select **Replace All** then enter replace word ex:AM1
- Press OK

Note: Don't forget to select **Case Sensitive** and **Whole World** option while searching and file extension **.java**.
You have to do it JUST 4 times for 4 cases.

Comment: References still need to be updated manually, right? This part hurts more than the file name replacement.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK yeah, you mentioned to update the references, so I wanna know if there's an automatic way to update these references? because there're 1000+ class names that need to be updated

Comment: @hsluoyz No need to update references manually. As said in my post the first part explains the file renaming thus you will get compiler errors on import.Second part explains how to update the references. Note that the replacement also happens in comments and limited to java class files. If my post doesn’t answer your question completely then edit your question and explain **what exactly you want** and **what is missing in my answer**. Avoid commenting further. This also get attention of new users on your question.

Comment: @hsluoyz were you able to find a solution that does not require manually updating each of the references?